# Merging two functions into one

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that increments numbers (inc), and another that decrements numbers (dec).

I would like to merge them into one as follows:

`newFunction(inc, 8)` should run `inc(8)` and
`newFunction(dec, 3)` should run `dec(3)`

I tried different things but nothing worked so far. Thank you in advance!

Comment: so, will `dec` and `inc` still exist? if not, what will `enc` and `dec` be, since you pass that as an argument to `newFunc`

Comment: please add `inc` and `dec`.

Answer (score 2):

```
const run = (fn, value) => fn(value)

run(inc, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as a callback, and use spread for aguments

```js
function newFunction(callback, ...functionArguments) {
  return callback(...functionArguments);
}

newFunction(console.log, "Works with one argument");
newFunction(console.log, "as",  "well", "as",  "with", "multiple");
```

As you can tell from the code snipper the function `console.log` got called in both cases